# R, sf package: Buffers and points are not showing on map

Tags: r, geolocation, mapping, r-sf, geo

Thank you for taking the time to read.

I have no idea why this code is not working. To summarize (changing variable names), I have locations of restaurants in St. Louis (coordinates, lat and long), as well as locations of convenience stores (also in lat long). I want to see how often a convenience store is 1000 feet from a restaurant.

```
#Bring in data
# MO county data
county.sf <- get_acs(state = "MO",
     county = c("St. Louis County", "St. Louis City"),
                 geography = "tract",
                 variables = "B03002_001", 
                 output="wide", 
                 geometry = TRUE) %>%
sf::st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003")
class(county.sf)

# Restaurant data
res <- read.csv("Myfile1.csv")
res.sf <- st_as_sf(res, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = st_crs(county.sf))
res.sf.utm <- st_transform(res.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")

# Store data
store <- import("Myfile2.csv")
store.sf <- st_as_sf(store, coords = c("Latitude", "Longitude"), crs = st_crs(county.sf))
store.sf.utm <- st_transform(store.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")

# Creating buffers
# Going to use 1000 ft which = 304.8 meter buffers
elem.buff <-st_buffer(res.sf.utm, 304)     
class(elem.buff)

#Create Map
ex.map<- tm_shape(county.sf) + tm_polygons() + tm_shape(elem.buff) + tm_borders(col="red") + tm_shape(res.sf.utm) + tm_dots(col = "red") + tm_shape(store.sf.utm) + tm_dots()
```

ex.map

This code all runs, and even shows a map of the two counties in St. Louis I am interested in. But despite the coordinates of the restaurants and stores being in those counties, nothing shows up. There is some kind of mismatch where the files are not matching. I have no idea how to fix this.

Sample data:

Myfile1.csv | RestaurantName |     lat           |         long       |
|   Joes Diner   | 38.705222421313   |   -90.3084172639293|

Myfile2.csv | Store Name     |     Latitude       |      Longitude       |
|   SuperShop    | 38.5420000000000   |   -90.2700000000000  |

Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For myfile1.csv, you aren't using the correct field names for your coords i.e. `st_as_sf(...,coord = c("long","lat")...)`. `crs=` for points should also be geographic (e.g. `crs=4326`), then transform to match your polygons.

Comment: I am not sure if I 100% understand. Does longitude go before latitude here? 

And do I just change all crs values to 4326? Sorry, very new to mapping here.

Comment: No problem. My first point in my first comment was that your coordinate fields in your sample data are "long" and "lat" rather than "longitude" and "latitude" like is in your code. The second point is addressed by @Wesley's answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your coordinate reference system (crs). In these two lines, you convert the csv files to spatially referenced points, and tell them to use the crs of the `county.sf` shapefile:

```
res.sf <- st_as_sf(res, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = st_crs(county.sf))
store.sf <- st_as_sf(store, coords = c("Latitude", "Longitude"), crs = st_crs(county.sf))
```

But you've earlier transformed `county.sf` to use the `ESRI:102003` crs, which is a projection, not lat-long coordinates. When you convert the csv to spatial points, you need to tell `st_as_sf()` which crs the csv uses. In this case, that is lat-long, which usually means the `epsg:4326` crs. You also need to specify `long` as the first coordinate, as it is the "x" direction and `lat` is the "y". So, replace the above lines with these:

```
# create the spatial points, matching the lat/long coding of the csv
res.sf <- st_as_sf(res, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs="epsg:4326")
store.sf <- st_as_sf(store, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs="epsg:4326")
```

Comment: Nice answer! I just want to point out for future readers that lat/longs doesn't necessarily imply the use of the WGS84 (epsg 4326) geographic coordinate system, although its usually a good guess. More info here: https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf

Comment: Oh wow, this worked! Thank you so much for your help!